# Optimizing Memory Allocation in PyTorch GEMM Operations for Small Inputs and Large Weight Matrices on CPU？

Tags: caching, memory-management, pytorch, malloc, large-language-model

In the field of neural networks, it is common to have a sequence of linear layers implemented using PyTorch, where operations like multiple General Matrix Multiply (GEMM) computations are performed on the CPU, such as $x_1A=x_2, x_2B=x_3,...$. Typically, the input and output values $x_i$ are small, while the weight matrices $A, B,...$ are relatively large.

In PyTorch's GEMM operator, for example, in the operation $x_1A=x_2$, PyTorch needs to allocate a block of memory for the output $x_2$, and the GEMM operator writes the result to this allocated memory. If $x_i$ is small enough to fit into the cache, it inevitably requires repeated memory allocation for the output values during consecutive operations. The allocated memory is loaded into the cache when outputting the result, and the cache is refreshed. For the next GEMM operation, the data is read directly from the cache. However, due to PyTorch's tensor garbage collection, when $x_i$ is evicted, it may no longer be needed, but it still triggers a write back (the tensor is evicted before the garbage collection is triggered), causing unnecessary writes.

Is there an interface, similar to the concept of a meta device in PyTorch, for allocating memory in the cache, where the content is meaningless, and during writing, loading is not required (since the allocated memory is initialized and does not need loading)? Alternatively, is it possible to allocate a portion of the cache as memory and directly allocate space for $x$ in the cache?